# SSIS issue for <Execute Process Task> for path with the space with Power Shell

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to fix inherited SSIS package and identified that the problem  is the the space in the Path.
I defentiley did my homework and testing with all double qoutes and escapes, but nothing is working, that string that produces this error works just fine in the Power Shell window. I use  variable to set a path but I doesn't matter, same result if I type in inside the argument string.
What I'm missing here?  I'm SSIS 2016 that `dir` command is part of the piped command to delete old files, for testing purposes I cut it. Local or \network drive works the same.
Originally:

```
dir \\myserver\ESD\My Backup\*.xlsx |? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7)} | del
```

Below is pic with all my setup
[image]

Thanks Gigga!!, I tested with `PowerShell -NoExit` before command and here the output, those double quotes got lost somewhere.. Suprisengly that it worked fine before, could be some W update??)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you'll get more information about the error by using "Powershell -NoExit" at the beginning of arguments list (described here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/98e19d1f-1a7e-498d-b34a-4588145dcfca/ssis-execute-process-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Thanks G!  Super good link, I will check. Note that exact string works fine from PowerShell command line (that black window at the left bottom),   Something is specific about SSIS

Comment: Thanks Gigga again, I tested it now and see that space inside the name was not treated right even with double quotes. Will try something else.

Comment: Looks like there is NO solution for powershell, I finished replacing it with C# script which works perfectly.  Still a mistery what happened with that PowerShell / or MSDT during April 2021?  I remind that before it worked OK

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have already find a workaround but I think that the issue in SSIS can be sorted by combining double and single quotes. If you write the expression like this should work:

```
"dir 'c:\\ESD\My BackupX\\*.xlsx'"
```

Comment: Tx J! it worked, I didn't think about putting everything into "